# User input changing which activity a button will open

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I'm attempting to make a simple addition game, with two randomly generated numbers. When the user inputs an answer, it will either go to the correct or incorrect activity depending on their answer after hitting a button. I can't get my "additionAnswer" to carry through classes and for it to be compared to the number which the user inputs. Here's the code:

```
public class Addition extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button button9;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addition);
        addListenerOnButton();
        Random addition1 = new Random();
        int additionInt1 = addition1.nextInt(100)+1;
        TextView additionText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
        String additionString1 = String.valueOf(additionInt1);
        additionText1.setText(additionString1);
        Random addition2 = new Random();
        int additionInt2 = addition2.nextInt(100)+1;
        TextView additionText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
        String additionString2 = String.valueOf(additionInt2);
        additionText2.setText(additionString2);
        int additionAnswer = additionInt1 + additionInt2;
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        final Context context = this;
        button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        button9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(textview5 = additionAnswer) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Correct.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Incorrect.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to convert the `text` to an `integer`.

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    final Context context = this;
    button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    button9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check for 'textview5.getText()' is null
            if (textview5.getText()!=null && (Integer.valueOf(textview5.getText().toString()) == additionAnswer)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Correct.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Incorrect.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
}
```